# Castle Windsor: Inject child dependencies via method after dependency resolves

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have the following unit of work. It's composed to allow me to add repositorie via my IOC, and then access those repositories in my services based on type - without having to rewrite the unit of work each time a new repository comes on the scene. From the research I've done, using Activator for this is not enough of a performance impact to worry about.

```
public class DbContextUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
   public DbContextUnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext))
   {
       // Set DbContext
   }

   public void AddRepository<T>() where T : IRepository
   {
       // Activate T and inject DbContext
       // Add to singleton list
   }

   public T GetRepository<T>() where T : IRepository
   {
       // If T exists on list return T
   }

   // Other methods such as save, dispose, etc.
}
```

My question is, how do I configure Windsor so that when it finishes resolving DBContextUnitOfWork I can explicitly call the AddRepository method on it for every repository I need to add?

Comment: What do you mean *I can explicitly call the AddRepository method on it for every repository I need to add?*

Comment: So if I register the unit of work component with windsor, I would like to be able to also specify that a particular number of repositories are added to it via the AddRepository method. This would happen before the unit of work is injected into which ever class requires it. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're adding the repositories because they'll be needed at some later point.  The usual approach is to register the repository types with Windsor, and ask Windsor to resolve the repository at *that* point, rather than using the activator to create them up front.

Comment: What if I were to abstract the windsor container into an IDependencyResolver interface, and injected that into the UnitOfWork. Is that good practice?

Comment: @ChrisPaynter: If that UnitOfWork is part of your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) (thus an infrastructural component), it's okay to inject an `IDependencyResolver`, but in that case injecting the windows container directly would do the same. When the UnitOfWork is part of the application, this would be considered bad practice, because you now use the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

Comment: UnitOfWork is part of the composition root yes. By wrapping the IOC into an IDependencyResolver, the UnitOfWork is IOC agnostic so I can create an IDependencyResolver for whichever IOC a project is using, and still use this UnitOfWork. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I worked out I could use Component.For().UsingFactory(), and I could register a custom factory which built the UnitOfWork for me.